# Nexio Touchscreen

Tags: touchscreen

I have a 15" Nexio USB IR touchscreen connected and 'lsusb' identifies as:

```
ID 1870:0001 Nexio Co., Ltd iNexio Touchscreen controller
```

I have verified on a Windows PC that the device registers touches and am now trying to get it to work on my Raspberry Pi3 (Jessie 4.4 released on 2016-05-27)

My investigating has quickly gotten outside my area of knowledge and I am seeking help on how I would go about getting this working.

Update:

I've narrowed the situation down to the touchscreen does work on the RPi but only if it is connected AFTER the desktop has loaded, and it will only function for this first instance. A dis/reconnect will cause it to be non-functional again until a reboot.

I do get the following modprobe error from dmesg when it is connected at startup

```
usbtouchscreen: probe of 1-1.5:1.1 failed with error -110
```

Connecting an ELO touchscreen works in all expected cases. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Error 110 is ETIMEDOUT meaning ["connection timed out"](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4-rc2/source/include/uapi/asm-generic/errno.h#L93). The same issue is discussed at https://what.thedailywtf.com/topic/26332/linux-usb-device-keeps-disconnecting-and-reconnecting.

Driver and firmware have been abandoned on Linux, so the only solution I see is to buy a different device with active vendor support.

Comment: And what is the solution to the question?

Comment: Buy a different device with active vendor support, I'm afraid.